# Validate all fields in Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, validation

I have a Question. I created a Swing GUI Form. This form contain JTextFields, JComboBox components.

Now what i want to do, when user pressing **completed** button i want to validate JTextFields and JComboBox component. I want to write common method for all JTextFields and another common method for JComboBoxes. Does anyone know about validate API?

**I dont need to validate all fields one by one.**

Comment: what do you meaning, whats validations (in container, value from, e.i. ???.)

Comment: You could have a look at [JGoodes bindings](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "validation" means "check all the fields" ... then, yes - your "validate" routine will check all the fields one-by-one :)

You can also "validate-as-you-go".  There are many ways to accomplish this, including:

- [Kenai Simple Validation API](http://kenai.com/projects/simplevalidation/pages/Home)
- [InputVerifier](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20551.html)
- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/InputVerifierExample.htm

Comment: I think Kenai Validation API is useful. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 8):

One option here would be to use Swing's `InputVerifier` to validate input for every `JComboBox` & `JTextField` used. You could share common verifiers between components:

```
   public class MyNumericVerifier extends InputVerifier {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
           String text = null;

           if (input instanceof JTextField) {
             text = ((JTextField) input).getText();
           } else if (input instanceof JComboBox) {
             text = ((JComboBox) input).getSelectedItem().toString();
           }

           try {
              Integer.parseInt(text);
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              return false;
           }

           return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
           boolean valid = verify(input);
           if (!valid) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid data");
           }

           return valid;
       }
    }

InputVerifier verifier = new MyNumericVerifier()
comboBox.setInputVerifier(verifier);
```

Comment: +1 You can provide feedback in `shouldYieldFocus()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510756/230513).

Answer (score 2):

There are some third party api's available. You can develop your own for

1. Required field,
2. Email Validation,
3. Max & Min length, etc.,

Here is a sample tutorial for [Building a Swing Validation Package with InputVerifier](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20551.html)

Comment: See also this `JTable` related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13510756/230513).

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Instead you will have to create a new class that inherits the JTextField and then have a `validate()` function as `private` or `protected`, and call that everytime you `getText()` (which means you'll have to `@Override` it)from it.

An alternate is to use `Container.getComponent()` and check for `instanceof` and then validate each field separately. This however is against what you're asking for.