# How to add an "input value" listener to a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I have a JTable. Currently I have the following code:

```
     table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
     JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
     int row = target.getSelectedRow();

     int   value = Integer.parseInt( (String) table.getValueAt(row, 0));
     int x = 0,y=0;
     if (row==1) {x=582;y=483;} else if (row==2) {x=221;y=575;} else if (row==3) {x=231;y=435;}
     boundaryFill4(x, y, value, 50);

     my.setIcon(new ImageIcon(buffered));

            }
          }
        });
```

But I need to make my JTable to update itself automatically as user types in new values. The mouse listener does not do exactly what I want. It would update as the user points the cursor to the JTable cell. I could not find any "input value update" listener in documentation.

I could use keyListener, but in that case I will need to add an "UPDATE" JButton, but I need the JTable to update itself automatically without JButton.

The third method would be to create an infinite update loop : while(true) { //update}
But this takes a lot of computer memory...and is not efficient way.

Can anybody recommend me how to improve my code OR can anybody correct the above MouseListener. Thank You!

Comment: Do you want your listener to be called every time the user types a key, or when the user finishes entering a value in a cell?

Comment: when the user finishes entering a value in a cell

Comment: that's not how editing a table cell is supposed to work: it's meant to be type-all-then-commit scenario. Taking a step back, the question is: why do you need a commit-on-typed? Re-reading your last comment leaves me confused: updating when the user commits the value is default behaviour, so what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), you can make every cell editable by choosing how you construct your `TableModel`. For control of individual cells, override `isCellEditable()` in your `TableModel`. If you still have problems, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your chosen approach.

Addendum: *I just was curious if there is a "Input" listener.*

You may be looking for a [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13510756/230513).

Comment: Thank you, but I have no problems with the JTable per se. I have an additional ExcelAdapter class. I just was curious if there is a "Input" Listener. I know there is a "input key" listener, but that does not provide an immidiate update on the runtime. Currently my code is updating using an infinite loop: while(true)...which is probably not the best option.