# How to disable a specific cell with JPopupmenu's JMenuItem?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, jpopupmenu

I have created a simple JTable and wish to be able to disable a cell after right clicking it and selecting the option in the JPopupMenu with a JMenuItem that will disable the selected cell, here's my MouseAdapter:

```
private JPopupMenu popup;
private JMenuItem one;

table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int r = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        if (r >= 0 && r < table.getRowCount()) {
            table.setRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
        } else {
            table.clearSelection();
        }
        int rowindex = table.getSelectedRow();
        if (rowindex < 0)
            return;
        if (e.isPopupTrigger() && e.getComponent() instanceof JTable) {
            int rowIndex = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            int colIndex = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

            one = new JMenuItem("Disable this cell");
            popup = new JPopupMenu();
            popup.add(one);
            popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
});
```

Now, I know you can disable particular cell(s) by doing:

```
DefaultTableModel tab = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

but this is disabling the cell on creation of JTable but I need to disable the cell after creation. Any ideas/leads on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify your `TableModel` to add storage for the desired *editable* state of each cell, e.g. `List<Boolean>`. Your model can return the stored state from `isCellEditable()`, and your mouse handler can set the desired state in your `TableModel`. You may need the model/view conversion methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16235277/230513).